# Webservice having trouble pass back to client

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, web-services

I having trouble passing back the result which is multiple row getting from MS-SQL2012 to client. I have tried to google up but still not find the solution. Since I'm new in .NET and this is my first webservice, required an assistant to solve my problem or suggest any better solution.

[Result need to pass back to client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13ZVy.png)

```
Public Class Service1
Inherits System.Web.Services.WebService

Public Class Dealer
    Public IDNo, ICFound, POFound As String
End Class

<WebMethod()> _
Public Function DailyCheckDealer(records As String()()) As String
    Dim mylist As List(Of String()) = records.ToList()
    Dim datarow As String = ""
    Dim result As String = "Done"

    For i As Integer = 0 To mylist.Count - 1
        Dim m As String() = mylist(i)
        For j As Integer = 0 To m.Length - 1
            datarow += m(j) + " "
        Next
    Next

    //Insert the array into the database. 

    Dim objDealer As New Dealer
    Dim myConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MM_CONNECTION_STRING_iPRIS")
    Dim myConnection1 = New SqlConnection(myConnString)
    Dim myCommand = New SqlCommand()
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    myCommand.Connection = myConnection1
    myCommand.CommandText = "DailyCheckDealer"
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@DataRow", SqlDbType.VarChar, 8000).Value = datarow
    myConnection1.Open()
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    myConnection1.Close()

    // Get the record(s) after processing and return it back to client

    Dim myConnection2 = New SqlConnection(myConnString)
    Dim objComm As New SqlCommand("Select IDNo, IDFound, POFound From DailyDealerCheck Order By IDNo", myConnection2)
    myConnection2.Open()
    Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = objComm.ExecuteReader()
    If sdr.Read() Then
        objDealer.IDNo = sdr("IDNo").ToString()
        objDealer.ICFound = sdr("IDFound").ToString()
        objDealer.POFound = sdr("POFound").ToString()
    End If
    myConnection2.Close()
    Return objDealer
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting your data and putting it into objDealer which is an instance of type Dealer. You then actually have `Return objDealer`

Clrearly you want to return an instance of Dealer. However your function is declared as returning a string. That shouldn't even compile! Change the declaration to this:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function DailyCheckDealer(records As String()()) As Dealer
```

That will allow it to return a Dealer not a string.

EDIT - to return more than one Dealer:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function DailyCheckDealer(records As String()()) As List(Of Dealer)

' code left out

Dim myConnection2 = New SqlConnection(myConnString)
Dim objComm As New SqlCommand("Select IDNo, IDFound, POFound From DailyDealerCheck Order By IDNo", myConnection2)
' Create list of Dealers for return
Dim dealerList as New List(Of Dealer)

myConnection2.Open()
Dim sdr As SqlDataReader = objComm.ExecuteReader()
If sdr.Read() Then
    objDealer.IDNo = sdr("IDNo").ToString()
    objDealer.ICFound = sdr("IDFound").ToString()
    objDealer.POFound = sdr("POFound").ToString()
    ' Add the latest to the list
    dealerList.Add(objDealer)
End If
myConnection2.Close()

' Return list of dealers
Return dealerList
End Function
```

Comment: Thank Simon. Change as recommended, at least it return a value. For you info there are 10 records result from the query but only 1 record return to client. If you don't mind can you show me how to put the return value in array.

Comment: Your extended list is not working. By enhanced it, it work. But now I have one more problem where return value are empty when I run my asmx.